# Json object doesn't appear on broswer

Tags: node.js, json

Hello I use nodeJS and I want to create an application in which I want to make a post request with a Json object from Postman or curl, my app will fetch Json Object and it will appear the object in broswer.

So, I tried to do that , but I have the problem that the json Object don't appear on broswer
(I use npm hbs, but also I tried it without that).

my nodeJS code is:

```
app.use(express.json())      
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use('/notify',(req,res)=>{
    
    const json = req.body
    console.log(json)
    res.render('index' , {
        title: 'Weather App',
        name:'ApLaz',
        expect: JSON.stringify(json) // I tried and without JSON.stringify
    }) 
})
```

With Postman request I send for example that

```
{
    "test": "ok",
    "var": 12
}
```

The result from console.log is :

```
{ ok: 'ok', var: 12 }
```

But on the broswer I just take this:

```
{}
```

This is my website

[image]

Why I can't appear my Json Object on broswer?

This is my index file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        {{>header}}
        <!-- End Header -->
        
        <div>
          <p>Use this site for the Weather</p>

          <form id="formSearch">
            <input placeholder='Location' id="inputSearchValue">
            <button>Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p id="location">{{expect}}</p>
        
        <p id="forecast"></p>

        <!-- Footer -->
        {{>footer}}
        <!-- End Footer -->

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In postman did you set content-type header to application/json?

Comment: yes I used that

Comment: Please show your index, thanks.

Comment: I posted it in my question

Comment: may I found the problem. My data don't fetched in real time from my website . I have to reload it when I do some changes , so may this is the problem.

Comment: you could change your top body tag to `<body onload="()=>setTimeout(()=>window.reload(),5000)">` It's not a good way to do it but for learning it's fine. Not tested... =)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't crearly :( , when I reload the page I don't get the json object, just I see the changes in `title` or in  `name` not in `expect`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the info I need to exactly match your setup but here is a close approach. Keep in mind this is not how you would do it in a actually site but will work for learning.

You can think of dataStore as a temporary database that only exist while the app is running. In the index.html I commented out/disabled the following: header, footer, and  as you didn't provided and I don't want to create them :D

I suggest you continue along the FreeCodeCamp path as it will cover data storage down the road.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mustache": "^4.1.0",
    "mustache-express": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

src/index.js

```
const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')


let dataStore = {
    expect: {user: 'jdoe', age: 30},
}

app.use('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index' , {
        title: 'Weather App',
        name:'ApLaz',
        expect: JSON.stringify(dataStore.expect) // I tried and without JSON.stringify
    })
})

app.use('/notify',(req,res)=>{

    const json = req.body
    console.log(json)
    dataStore.expect = json
    res.render('index' , {
        title: 'Weather App',
        name:'ApLaz',
        expect: JSON.stringify(dataStore.expect)
    })
})


app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log('server listening on port: %s', 3000);
})
```

src/view/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header -->
<!-- >header}}-->
<!-- End Header -->

<div>
    <p>Use this site for the Weather</p>

    <form id="formSearch">
        <input placeholder='Location' id="inputSearchValue">
        <button>Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<p id="location">{{expect}}</p>

<p id="forecast"></p>

<!-- Footer -->
<!-- >footer}}-->
<!-- End Footer -->

<!--<script src="js/app.js"></script>-->
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To start the app open a terminal and run `yarn start` or `npm start`